# JQGrid select row checkboxclick

Tags: select, jqgrid, checkbox, click

I try to receive row id of JQGrid on checkbox click like:

```
loadComplete : function() {
    jQuery(".jqgrow td input").each(function() {
        jQuery(this).click(function() {
            var grid = $("#list");
            var rowid = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            alert(rowid);
        });
    });
}
```

But row is not selected - so I always receive a null.
What can be the reason?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is `var rowid = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');` will only contain `rowid` if you have already selected a row by clicking on the row before.

If you want an alternative, then you can select the checkbox on `onSelectRow` instead

```
onSelectRow: function(id,status){
    var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id); 
    var ch = jQuery(this).find('#'+id+' input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked');
    if(ch) {
        jQuery(this).find('#'+id+' input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',false);
    } else {
        jQuery(this).find('#'+id+' input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',true);                       
    }

    rowChecked=1;
    currentrow=id;
}
```

Comment: This answer didn't directly apply to my own issue but I voted it up because it led indirectly to resolving my own checkbox/jqGrid issue: how to get the checked checkboxes on just one single row when you know the `rowid`.

`$('#' + rowid + ' input[type=checkbox]').each(function (i) {`

`if (this.checked == true) {`

  `alert($(this).attr('id'));`

`}`

        });`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `onSelectRow` event built in jqGrid?

You can read more about jqGrid events [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents)

Comment: Because I need only on click on checkbox. onSelectRow I use for select row for delet.